# Spring RestTemplate ResponseEntity body is blank

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am calling a client Endpoint :
    `ResponseEntity<String> responseBody = restTemplate.exchange(destEndpoint, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);`

But when I call :
    `responseBody.getBody();`
I get blank response.

But When I use interceptor(ClientHttpRequestInterceptor) and log response I can see the response body is printed.
`List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
            interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);`

I did try extending the class `HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String>` and while debugging I can only see header and status and there is no body in the response object.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I was not getting any error. The problem was : interceptor was using InputStreamReader to log the body and the contents were reset and the response body was getting lost. I removed the InputStreamReader and it is working correct now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: thanks a lot @shadab you helped me a lot =D